# No route matches [POST] "/buddies" Following Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3.2

(Rails 3.2 newbie, App is twitter)

I wish I understood routes, but I still don't. I've setup a system where users can follow other users by submitting their username manually:

```
@relationship = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
if @relationship
  if current_user.following? @relationship
    current_user.unfollow @relationship
  else
    current_user.follow @relationship
  end
else
  flash[:notice] = "User with username #{params[:username]} is not found"
end
```

Which spits out this:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

That didn't really work until I changed @relationship to :relationship in view like this:

```
<%= form_for :relationship do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :username, placheholder: "username" %>
</div>
<br/>
<%= f.submit "Add/Subtract" %>
<% end %>
```

Now that error message ("User with username..") pops up all-the-time BUT when I click "Add/Subtract" it changes to this:

> No route matches [POST] "/buddies"

All this is under the User model.

I imagine something is terribly wrong.

EDIT: Routes looks like this.. (ribbit = tweets)

```
 Ribbitapp::Application.routes.draw do

   resources :ribbits
   resources :relationships
   resources :sessions
   resources :users


   get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

   #get 'buddies', to: 'users#buddies', as: 'buddies'

   match 'buddies', to: 'users#buddies', as: 'buddies'

   root to: 'users#new'
```

Comment: what have you mentioned for the same in your `routes.rb`

Comment: Added routes.rb, I don't know what to mention where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match 'buddies', to: 'users#buddies', as: 'buddies'` it should be like this in your routes

Comment: Match supports all the ones right? It appears to solved that problem, but the error "User with username..." still comes up constantly. Tried to follow a user and nothing showed... Thank you tho.

Comment: check your logs. I am sure that you have following params: `{relationship: {username: 'entered_value' }}`. It means that in controller you have not `params[:username]` but `params[:relationship][:username]`

Comment: The `development.log` file? I changed the params in the controller. I also am checking to see if I should change `:relationship` back to `@relationship`

Comment: The problem I was speaking of was the error that @govta and i wrote in the controller to check for blanks and valid users.

Comment: you mean you are always getting executed the `else` part of your controller code??

Comment: tell me what you are getting in your params??

Comment: Yes, my else is not doing what was intended. It needs to only show up if :username is invalid or blank. What do you mean by getting params?

Comment: what parameters are you getting in your controller??

Comment: says params[:username]